# Running stages in parallel with Jenkins workflow / pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

> **Please note:** the question is based on the old, now called "scripted" pipeline format. When using "declarative pipelines", parallel blocks can be nested inside of stage blocks (see [Parallel stages with Declarative Pipeline 1.2](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/)).

I'm wondering how parallel steps are supposed to work with Jenkins workflow/pipeline plugin, esp. how to mix them with build stages. I know about the general pattern:

```groovy
parallel(firstTask: {
  // Do some stuff
}, secondTask: {
  // Do some other stuff in parallel
})
```

However, I'd like to run couple of stages in parallel (on the same node, which has multiple executors), so I tried to add stages like this:

```groovy
stage 'A'
// Do some preparation stuff

parallel(firstTask: {
  stage 'B1'
  // Do some stuff
}, secondTask: {
  stage 'B2'
  // Do some other stuff in parallel
})

stage 'C'
// Finalizing stuff
```

This does not work as expected. The "do stuff" tasks are executed in parallel, but the parallel stages end immediately and do not incorporate the stuff they should contain. As a consequence, the Stage View does not show the correct result and also does not link the logs.

Can I build different stages in parallel, or is the "parallel" step only meant to be used within a single stage?

Comment: What exaclty doesn't work? I tried your snippet in Jenkins some minutes ago and it seems to work just fine.

Comment: As I said, the work steps are not really done as part of the stages, i.e. the Stage View does not show the time spent for them, and also no logs. If you do the same steps non-parallel, you'll see the difference.

Comment: I see - so the issue can only be seen in the stage view, right?

Comment: I think the situation changed: https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/

Comment: See my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46834998/scripted-jenkinsfile-parallel-stage/53456430#53456430

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You may not place the deprecated non-block-scoped `stage` (as in the original question) inside `parallel`.

As of [JENKINS-26107](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26107), `stage` takes a block argument. You may put `parallel` inside `stage` or `stage` inside `parallel` or `stage` inside `stage` etc. However visualizations of the build are not guaranteed to support all nestings; in particular

- The built-in *Pipeline Steps* (a “tree table” listing every step run by the build) shows arbitrary `stage` nesting.
- The [*Pipeline Stage View* plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Stage+View+Plugin) will currently only display a linear list of stages, in the order they started, regardless of nesting structure.
- [Blue Ocean](https://jenkins.io/projects/blueocean/) will display top-level stages, plus `parallel` branches inside a top-level stage, but currently no more.

[JENKINS-27394](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27394), if implemented, would display arbitrarily nested `stage`s.

Comment: I just read [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Stage+Step+Plugin) that as of v 2.1 the stage step inside a parallel is not usable, as it wasn't ever supported. Can you please tell me what the current status of this is?

Comment: In v2.2 of the pipeline-stage-step plugin stages take blocks. Although it still has the check to see if it's inside parallel, I've not seen it throw an exception. Typically I use a block too `parallel([thingA: { stage('A') { echo('A') } }])`. Note that it will look weird in both the standard UI and blue ocean. See [JENKINS-38442](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27394)

Comment: @ZombieDev, v2.2 throws exception for me using declarative pipeline. This usage does not pass declarative-linter.

Answer (score 26):

that syntax is now deprecated, you will get this error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 14: Expected a stage @ line 14, column 9.
       parallel firstTask: {
       ^

WorkflowScript: 14: Stage does not have a name @ line 14, column 9.
       parallel secondTask: {
       ^

2 errors
```

You should do something like:

```groovy
stage("Parallel") {
    steps {
        parallel (
            "firstTask" : {
                //do some stuff
            },
            "secondTask" : {
                // Do some other stuff in parallel
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Just to add the use of node here, to distribute jobs across multiple build servers/ VMs:

```groovy
pipeline {
  stages {
    stage("Work 1"){
     steps{
      parallel ( "Build common Library":   
            {
              node('<Label>'){
                  /// your stuff
                  }
            },
        
        "Build Utilities" : {
            node('<Label>'){
               /// your stuff
              }
           }
         )
    }
}
```

All VMs should be labelled as  to use as a pool.

Answer (score 16):

I have just tested the following pipeline and it works

```groovy
parallel firstBranch: {
    stage ('Starting Test') 
    {
        build job: 'test1', parameters: [string(name: 'Environment', value: "$env.Environment")]
    }
}, secondBranch: {
    stage ('Starting Test2') 
    {
        build job: 'test2', parameters: [string(name: 'Environment', value: "$env.Environment")]
    }
}
```

This Job named 'trigger-test' accepts one parameter named 'Environment'

Job 'test1' and 'test2' are simple jobs:

Example for 'test1'

- One parameter named 'Environment'
- Pipeline : echo "$env.Environment-TEST1"

**On execution, I am able to see both stages running in the same time**

Comment: which version of Jenkins?

Comment: as per @joao-cenoura - I really want this to work, but it doesn't work in 2.58 and I don't see anything in the release notes for 2.61 or the current plugins that sounds like they will make it work.  What version of Jenkins and the the pipeline plugins are you using?

Comment: Mine is "Jenkins ver. 2.46.2"

Comment: This works for me with version 2.65. You can have multiple stages within the parallel block definitions too.

Comment: it also stated here https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/

Answer (score 5):

I think this has been officially implemented now:
https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/

Answer (score 5):

As @Quartz mentioned, you can do something like

```groovy
stage('Tests') {
    parallel(
        'Unit Tests': {
            container('node') {
                sh("npm test --cat=unit")
            }
        },
        'API Tests': {
            container('node') {
                sh("npm test --cat=acceptance")
            }
        }
    )
}
```