# How to define parallel stages in a declarative Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am using Jenkins 2.73.1 and I am trying to define parallel stages using a declarative Jenkins file as follows:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    tools {
        jdk 'JDK8'
    }

    options {
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
        timestamps() // write timestamps in front of each console line
    }

    triggers {
        // Every minute
        pollSCM '*/1 * * * *'
    }

    stages {
        stage('Rüsten') {
            steps {
                bat "echo Hello"
            }
        }

        stage('Kochen (parallel)') {

            parallel {
                stage('Salzen') {
                    steps {
                        bat "echo Hello"
                    }        
                }
                stage('Rühren') {
                    steps {
                        bat "echo Hello"
                    }        
                }
                stage('Abschmecken') {
                    steps {
                        bat "echo Hello"
                    }        
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Essen') {
            steps {
                bat "echo Hello"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this results in the following compilation error.

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 25: Unknown stage section "parallel". Starting with version 0.5, steps in a stage must be in a steps block. @ line 25, column 9.
           stage('Kochen (parallel)') {
           ^

WorkflowScript: 25: Nothing to execute within stage "Kochen (parallel)" @ line 25, column 9.
           stage('Kochen (parallel)') {
           ^

2 errors

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:129)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:123)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:517)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:480)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:269)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:419)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Then I have found the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36872657/running-stages-in-parallel-with-jenkins-workflow-pipeline) on Stackoverflow and tried to apply their solutions but nothing worked for me.

Can someone tell me if it is possible to run stages or steps in parallel and how I can achieve it with Jenkins 2.73.1 (and greater)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That syntax is brand new and only available in the pipeline model definition plugin v 1.2+.

If you want to do it previous to that version, the syntax is not a pretty.

This has an example of the older syntax: https://gist.github.com/abayer/925c68132b67254147efd8b86255fd76