# Closures in Groovy not capturing outside variables

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In the context of Jenkins pipelines, I have some Groovy code that's enumerating a list, creating closures, and then using that value in the closure as a key to lookup another value in a map. This appears to be rife with some sort of anomaly or race condition almost every time.

This is a simplification of the code:

```
def tasks = [:]
for (platformName in platforms) {
  // ...

  tasks[platformName] = {
    def componentUploadPath = componentUploadPaths[platformName]

    echo "Uploading for platform [${platformName}] to [${componentUploadPath}]."

    // ...
}

tasks.failFast = true
parallel(tasks)
```

`platforms` has two values. I will usually see two iterations and two tasks registered and the keys in `tasks` will be correct, but the echo statement *inside the closure* indicates that we're just running one of the platforms twice:

```
14:20:02 [platform2] Uploading for platform [platform1] to [some_path/platform1].
14:20:02 [platform1] Uploading for platform [platform1] to [some_path/platform1].
```

It's ridiculous.

What do I need to add or do differently?

Comment: "almost every time"?  So you saw it working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the same issue as you'd see in Javascript.

When you generate the closures in a for loop, they are bound to a *variable*, not the *value* of the variable.

When the loop exits, and the closures are run, they will all be using the same value...that is -- the last value in the for loop before it exited

For example, you'd expect the following to print `1 2 3 4`, but it doesn't

```
def closures = []

for (i in 1..4) {
    closures << { -> println i }
}

closures.each { it() }
```

It prints `4 4 4 4`

To fix this, you need to do one of two things...  First, you could capture the *value* in a locally scoped variable, then close over this variable:

```
for (i in 1..4) {
    def n = i
    closures << { -> println n }
}
```

The second thing you could do is use groovy's `each` or `collect` as each time they are called, the variable is a different instance, so it works again:

```
(1..4).each { i ->
    closures << { -> println i }
}
```

For your case, you can loop over `platforms` *and* collect into a map at the same time by using `collectEntries`:

```
def tasks = platforms.collectEntries { platformName ->
  [
     platformName,
     { ->
        def componentUploadPath = componentUploadPaths[platformName]
        echo "Uploading for platform [${platformName}] to [${componentUploadPath}]."
     }
  ]
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What about just using `$it`? It seems to me that, in this case, Groovy will automatically assign the key from the map as $it in each closure, so it's just a matter of setting `def platformName = $it`.

Comment: With the for loop?  There is no `it`

Comment: No worries  glad I could help

Comment: Sorry, just noticed my `each` example was overly complex. Fixed now 

Comment: `closures*.call()` for the golf then ;)