# How can I run parallel jobs efficiently with a pipeline without having queueing of builds

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have a pipeline something like below.

```
    stage('Build, run, report') {
        for (int i = 0; i < components.size(); ++i){
            builds[i] = {
                stage('Build') {
                    build job: 'Build', parameters: [string(name: 'Component', value: component)]
                }

                stage('Run') {
                   build job: 'Run', parameters: [string(name: 'Component', value: component)]
                }

                stage('Reporting') {
                   'Reporting', parameters: [string(name: 'Component', value: component)]
                }
        }
        }
        parallel builds
```

Here "components" is a list coming from parameter of pipeline. I want to run the same flow according the number of component.

I have only one slave node with 4 executers. If I have 10 components 4 will start running immediately and the other 6 will be queued and will be waiting for the executer to be free.

I can get even more than 50 comonents in the list and having somany in the queue is not looking good and I don't feel this will be the right approach then.(I suspect there would be a limit of builds can be in queue also.)

Do we have a way to pause the parallel triggering till executers/slaves are available and resume one by one when the executer/slave is getting free ?

Or do we have a better way to handle it than parallel run in pipeline ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running stages in parallel with Jenkins workflow / pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36872657/running-stages-in-parallel-with-jenkins-workflow-pipeline)

Comment: @Justin Nimmo this is totally a different question from the above mentioned link

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself, but maybe you can consider using quiet period for the build job after every 4 count of components.

Comment: I have seen I can fix the quite period. But How will it be useful here ? If you can explain little more would be helpful.

Comment: As I said, I don't have a setup with multiple slaves to test this.....but this is what I had in mind. Use something like below to get average wait times for your builds (add the script below in post-build groovy script) ````job = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getItem("demo")
build = job.getLastBuild()
action = build.getAction(jenkins.metrics.impl.TimeInQueueAction.class)
println action.getQueuingDurationMillis()```` Then use the wait time as quiet period. This will not stop adding the builds to the queue, but wait pause the builds from getting triggered.

Comment: @Sushanth Thanks for the reply.. It was a new learning. I will try something around it and post the status here.