# Jenkins job is not running on both slave agents

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to run my Jenkins job on 2 slave agents `Personal_Pc` and `ELO_1` each one having different group name. But the job runs only on `Personal_Pc` and not on `ELO_1`.

```
pipeline
{
    agent {label "Personal_Pc" && "ELO_1"}

    stages
    {
        stage('Build')
        {
            steps
            {
                 archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'autoload.php,php_couchbase.dll,libcouchbase.dll,php.ini,application/**,src/**,system/**,uploads/**,vendor/**,.htaccess,index.php,spinner.svg,waiting_config.png', caseSensitive: false, defaultExcludes: false, onlyIfSuccessful: true
            }
        }
        stage('Copying POS files')
        {
            steps
            {
                copyArtifacts filter: 'autoload.php,application/**,src/**,system/**,uploads/**,vendor/**,.htaccess,index.php,spinner.svg,waiting_config.png', fingerprintArtifacts: true, projectName: 'Setup_Pipeline', selector: lastWithArtifacts(), target: 'C:\\server\\htdocs\\pos'
            }
        }
        stage('Copying LIB FILE DLL')
        {
            steps
            {
                copyArtifacts filter: 'libcouchbase.dll', fingerprintArtifacts: true, projectName: 'Setup_Pipeline', selector: lastWithArtifacts(), target: 'C:\\server\\apache\\bin'
            }
        }
        stage('Copying INI FILE')
        {
            steps
            {
                copyArtifacts filter: 'php.ini', fingerprintArtifacts: true, projectName: 'Setup_Pipeline', selector: lastWithArtifacts(), target: 'C:\\server\\php'
            }
        }
        stage('Copying PHP EXT FILE DLL')
        {
            steps
            {
                copyArtifacts filter: 'php_couchbase.dll', fingerprintArtifacts: true, projectName: 'Setup_Pipeline', selector: lastWithArtifacts(), target: 'C:\\server\\php\\ext'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Think it Mist be or not and

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running stages in parallel with Jenkins workflow / pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36872657/running-stages-in-parallel-with-jenkins-workflow-pipeline)

Comment: If you want the whole job to run on multiple agents, you have to launch it multiple times. Use a common label for the nodes it should run on and specify only this label in `agent`, which causes Jenkins to select one of the nodes that has free executor(s). Alternatively create a `parallel` section to run certain stages of a single job invocation on multiple nodes in parallel.

Comment: i used common label too like Group_1 but it only runs on single agent. i want to run the job on all nodes have same  label