# Allow next Jenkins job of same project to run before current job ended

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In our project, when a job has finished a specific stage, it will leave the current workspace and only continue remote work. At this point it would be possible to start processing the next job on the same pipeline without influencing the result of the first job.

That said, this question is not about triggering a dependent or downstream job, but just starting the next job on the current pipeline's queue.

Is it possible to declare that the next job may start as soon as the first job has finished a specific stage?

Here's an example:

```
                      When this stage has finished, the next job could start.              
                                              v
+------------+------------+------------+-------------+------------+------------+
|            |            |            |             |            |            |
| Preparing  | Building   | Testing    | Publishing  | Deploying  | Verifying  |
|            |            |            |             |            |            |
+------------+------------+------------+-------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Please clarify. At the `Publishing` stage do you want the first job to trigger a second job as a downstream job or do you want to this first job to trigger itself?

Comment: I edited my question and hopefully made more clear that the goal is to trigger the same pipeline again, or rather to start the next job on the queue without actually triggering the pipeline again.

Comment: Thanks! Yes it is possible with some scripting but Jenkins cannot do it without being told to do so. When a job triggers itself, it will only get `queued` and it will not `start` until the pervious pipeline is complete, but you can play around with it by using the option `build job: firstjob` inside the `Publishing` stage. Essentially you need to `get` some parameter or variable from the remote machine where your work is happening and the decisions needs to be scripting around those values. Can help further if you paste a working pipeline and info on the remote work.

Comment: Please check plugin options as well 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36872657/running-stages-in-parallel-with-jenkins-workflow-pipeline ... 
https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin

Answer (score -1):

> Is it possible to declare that the next job may start as soon as the
> first job has finished a specific stage?

Answer is **Yes**.
I presume that you wanted to start another job in current workspace then, without waiting either you can trigger a Parallel Stage or you can trigger another Job.
If you wanted to trigger another job on remote then it will go in waiting queue

Consider the following example.

Let's say above stage is defined under Pipeline job `Release_Job` and next job is named `Parallel_Job` and this job to be declare/Trigger after Publishing Stage.

Triggering condition can be if Publishing Stage is Successful then trigger `Parallel_Job` I have given reference which need
[build job plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/)

```
boolean publishingPassed = false

stage('Publishing') {
    try{
        sh 'publish project' // or any operation
    }catch (Exception e){
        publishingPassed = true
    }//catch
    if(publishingPassed){
        //trigger parallel job
        // make sure that you have build job plugin
        build job:'Parallel_Job' , parameters:[
        string(name: 'keyNameOfParam1',value: 'valueOfParam1')
        booleanParam(name: 'keyNameOfParam2',value:'valueOfParam2')
        // based on your need change job 
    }//buildPassed
}//building
```

Comment: This is not answering the query raised. The expectation is for a particular job A to trigger itself, not trigger another job B.