# "Ambiguous expression could be either a parameterless closure expression or an isolated open code block in jenkins parallel execution throws error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, cicd

following code is throwing below error.

if(!SkipLanguageComponentTests){

^

WorkflowScript: : Groovy compilation error(s) in script. Error(s): "Ambiguous expression could be either a parameterless closure expression or an isolated open code block;

solution: Add an explicit closure parameter list,
script {

2 errors

`

```
def SkipLanguageComponentTests = false; 
pipeline {
parameters {
    booleanParam(name: 'SkipLanguageComponentTests', defaultValue: false, description: 'XYZ')
}

stages {
    stage('Checkout Source') {
        steps {
            checkout scm
        }
    }      

    stage("Component & Language Tests"){
        steps{
            parallel (
                "componentTestsTask":{
                    //component test start
                    dir("docker"){
                        sh  script: "docker-compose -f blah blah\""
                    }
                    // some xyz step here
                    //component test ends here
                },
                "integrationTestTasks":{
                    // language test script starts
                    if(!SkipLanguageComponentTests){
                        
                        //run lang test and publish report 
                    } else {
                        echo "Skip Language Component Tests"
                    }
                    // language test script ends
                }
            )
            
        }
    }
```

}

`

I have tried as per the documentation https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/

I have tried this based on the answer mentioned in : [Running stages in parallel with Jenkins workflow / pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36872657/running-stages-in-parallel-with-jenkins-workflow-pipeline)
`stage("Parallel") { steps { parallel ( "firstTask" : { //do some stuff }, "secondTask" : { // Do some other stuff in parallel } ) } }`
Can someone help me to resolve this ?

Comment: You are using old `parallel()` syntax which isn't recommended anymore (except if you need _dynamic_ branches, which isn't the case here). Read about recommended declarative syntax [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parallel). Also, instead of `if` I suggest to use declarative [`when`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) to make sure skipped branch shows properly in Blue Ocean.

Comment: I have tried with new one it worked. but I have docker compose command in both in which one of them is failing. is there any options we can specify for each parallel step it chooses the node randomly?

Comment: You can specify `stage { agent { label 'YourLabel' } …` and if `YourLabel` is assigned to all nodes, it will choose the node randomly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here  is the working version of your pipeline - with proper IF inside:

```
    parameters {
        booleanParam(name: 'SkipLanguageComponentTests', defaultValue: false, description: '')
    }
    agent { label 'master' }
    stages {
        stage("Component & Language Tests") {
            parallel {
                stage("componentTestsTask") {
                    steps {
                        //component test start
                        echo "docker"
                        // some xyz step here
                        //component test ends here
                    }
                }
                stage("integrationTestTasks") {
                    steps {
                        script {
                            // language test script starts
                            if (!params.SkipLanguageComponentTests) {
                                echo "not skipped"
                                //run lang test and publish report
                            } else {
                                echo "Skip Language Component Tests"
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    // language test script ends
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This pipeline is not optimal, use below information to improve it.

Notes:

- you are using declarative pipeline so I think it is better to stay with parallel section expressed in declarative way
- help is here: [Jenkins doc about parallel](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parallel)
- there is scripted pipeline as well [Jenkins doc about scripted pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#scripted-pipeline)
- as I stated in original answer, you have to use *params* to refer to input parameter properly
- if you are using code you have to enclose it in script section - this is like putting scripted pipeline inside declarative one
- IF statement can also be done declaratively: [Jenkins doc about WHEN](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when)
- I recommend not to mix these 2 styles: so if you are using both for some good reason they should be separated from one another as much as possible for example by using function or library inside declarative pipeline - the goal is to have pipeline as clear and readable as possible

Answer (score -1):

You are using input variable, so try to refer as it should be done for input in Jenkins:

```
if(!params.SkipLanguageComponentTests)
```